# Animate UIView calling a method

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a function which should be start the animation. The triangle is designed in "drawrect", and I have a button in a controller, and when it's pressed, it calls "startTriangleAnimation".

The problem is the method "startTriagnleAnimation" is not adding the animation. I am sure that program enters in this method because it prints the NSLOG.

anyone know how to do?

```
- (void)startTriangleAnimation
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    if (_leftFoot) {
            NSLog(@"LEFT FOOT ANIMATION STARTING");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                              delay:0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-FIRST_ROTATION));
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                                                   delay:0.5
                                                 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                              animations:^{
                                                  self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-SECOND_ROTATION));
                                              } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                  [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                                                                        delay:0.5
                                                                      options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                                                   animations:^{
                                                                       self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-THIRD_ROTATION));
                                                                   }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                                       [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                                                                                        animations:^{
                                                                                            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-FOURTH_ROTATION));
                                                                                        }];
                                                                   }];
                                              }];
                         }];



    } else {
         NSLog(@"RIGHT FOOT ANIMATION STARTING");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                              delay:0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             NSLog(@"animating");
                             self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(FIRST_ROTATION));
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                                                   delay:0.5
                                                 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                              animations:^{
                                                  self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(SECOND_ROTATION));
                                              } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                  [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                                                                        delay:0.5
                                                                      options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                                                   animations:^{
                                                                       self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(THIRD_ROTATION));
                                                                   }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                                       [UIView animateWithDuration:15
                                                                                        animations:^{
                                                                                            self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(FOURTH_ROTATION));
                                                                                        }];
                                                                   }];
                                              }];
                         }];



    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat x = self.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat y = self.bounds.size.width;

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x/2, y - 20)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x/2 - 10, y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x/2 + 10, y)];
    [path closePath];
    [path fill];
    //[path stroke];

    if (_leftFoot) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(10));

    } else {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-10));


    }



}
```

Comment: That code indentation hurts my eyes ...and my heart

Comment: that's xcode identation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible explanation is that you have unexpected values in your FIRST_ROTATION etc variables.

Another one is that you rotate in drawRect. To my mind, this has unintended consequences. If you want your "base triangle" to be not straight just calculate the appropriate points for your path and draw it right away.

Comment: yeh but how to call the animation from outside?

Comment: You are not calling the animation from inside `drawRect`.